# Adding first 2 elements from one array and first 2 elements from another array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a third array of numbers by adding the 2 first elements from first array and 2 first elements from the second array and so on.
Example: `v1 { 1 2 3 4 } v2 { 5 6 7 8 }` 
and v3 should be `{ 1 2 5 6 3 4 7 8 }`

All I've done so far:

Thanks in advance!

```
int *v1,*v2,*v3,n,m,i,j;
scanf("%d",&n);
m=n;
v1=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
v2=(int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
v3=(int*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(int));

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&v1[i]);
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    scanf("%d",&v2[j]);

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    v3[i]=v1[i];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    v3[2+i]=v2[i];
printf("sir concatenat =\n");
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("v3[%d]= %d\n",i,v3[i]);
```

Comment: Whats the problem ? Besides you not `free`ing the allocated memory .

Comment: `v3=(int*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(int));` should be `v3=malloc((n+m)*sizeof(int));` you multiplied where you should add.

Comment: I dont know how to add the next elements, i know how to add the first two from both arrays,but i want them to continue ,like the example i showed up. 
 v1 { 1 2 3 4 }
 v2 { 5 6 7 8 }
 v3 { 1 2 5 6 3 4 7 8 }  i can only make 1 2 5 6 but not the rest.

Comment: You could have another indexing variable, say `int j=0;` and then your loops can do `v3[j++]=v1[i];` and so on.

Comment: Hmm, i will try this too. Thank you Weather Vane.

Comment: RM Faheem im not sure how to do that...

Comment: oh sorry i mistakenly pressed enter key for the next line instead of shift+enter

Comment: i explain the psuedo code, u can easily implement as 
use nested for loops:
in for loop i with increment of 4, 
and other sub loop j with increment of 2
assign v3(i) as jth element of v1 and v3(i+1) j+1 element of v1
assign v3(i+2) as jth elem of v2 and v3(i+4) as j+1 element of v2

I hope this will help..

Comment: Thank you RM. I will try to code what you've said, even though i'm having real problems with understanding algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make as few changes as possible. I hope this could help you.

The first mistake is the allocation of the resulting array of integer. It must be:

```
v3 = (int*)malloc((n + m)*sizeof(int));
```

The second problem is how to merge the two input arrays in order to obtain your final result.
This means you must for the first check if the input arrays are even or odd:

```
j = ((m % 2) != 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Then cycling on each input array with a step of two you can merge one after another the two input arrays in a way very similiar to your approach:

```
for (k = 0; k < m; k += 2) {
    for (i = k; i < (k + 2) && i < m; i++) {
        v3[k + i] = v1[i];
    }
    if (i >= m && j == 1) {
        v3[m + m - 1] = v2[m - 1];
    } else {
        for (i = k; i < (k + 2) && i < m; i++) {
            v3[k + i + 2] = v2[i];
        }
    }
}
```

In the following the full code:

```html
#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{
    int *v1, *v2, *v3, n, m, i, j, k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    m = n;
    v1 = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    v2 = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    v3 = (int*)malloc((n + m)*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &v1[i]);
    for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
        scanf("%d", &v2[j]);

    j = ((m % 2) != 0) ? 1 : 0;
    for (k = 0; k < m; k += 2) {
        for (i = k; i < (k + 2) && i < m; i++) {
            v3[k + i] = v1[i];
        }
        if (i >= m && j == 1) {
            v3[m + m - 1] = v2[m - 1];
        } else {
            for (i = k; i < (k + 2) && i < m; i++) {
                v3[k + i + 2] = v2[i];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("sir concatenat =\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (2 * m); i++)
        printf("v3[%d]= %d\n", i, v3[i]);
}
```

Comment: Only works for even number of elements,its great though,i couldn't think of this. But im having a hard time to understand what you did. Thank you gaemaf !

Comment: You should explain what changes you made and why

Comment: @M.M I hope now it's all ok! If not, let me know. Thanks so much